# How do I gauge the effectiveness of conditioning workouts that don't involve sets and reps?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises

I am looking for a way to see if one of my workouts is effective. I work on five to six day cycle where one of the days is usually done on a heavy bag with 6 rounds 2 minutes each with thirty seconds in between. I have some boxing training and experience. Is there a way to gauge the effectiveness of this workout or any other workout where an increase in weight or reps isn't entirely applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the efficacy of conditioning workouts usually rests on measuring the output of the workout, i.e. X per time unit, where X can be watts, miles, punches thrown, whatever. More vague methods of tracking progress include feeling fresh at the end of a workout, or being able to complete a given workout more quickly, being able to shorten rest periods, or being able to complete more rounds. Of course these all depend on maintaining a constant work output.

Resting heart rate is another possibility for longer-term tracking of conditioning capability. With your specific example of bag work, there's also the traditional method of testing boxing conditioning: spar a few rounds, or take a fight.

There are more complex tests as well, which involve measuring heart rate or other indicators, or even looking at daily blood work.